# ¿Como hacer que un tag <canvas> se pueda ver en modo pantalla completa con funcion JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, ajax, asp.net-mvc

¿Como puedo hacer para que una grafico (canvas) se pueda ver en modo de pantalla completa ?

He revisado y encontre formas de hacerlo como por ejemplo : http://untitled.es/canvas-pantalla-completa/

Pero el problema que presento es que el grafico proviene de una vista parcial que se muestra en mi pagina.

Html

```
 <input type="submit" id="fullScreen" name="fullScreem" value="FS" class="btn" onclick="PantallaCompleta()" />
            <div class="col-md-8" >
                <div class="flot-chart dashboard-chart" >
                    <div class="flot-chart-content" id="flot-dashboard-chart"></div>
                </div>
```

JS

```
function PantallaCompleta ()
{
// AQUI EL CODIGO QUE NESECITO
}
```

Comment: Tan sencillo como `canvasElement.requestFullScreen()`

Comment: Ni tan sencillo por que no funciona como te digo el elemento no esta en el DOM de la pagina esta en un archivo externo

Comment: Si no está en la página no se puede ver, ni en pantalla completa ni en otro modo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como el canva estaba en una vista parcial y no dentro de la pagina que renderiza el navegador ...entonces hize que se viera en modo pantalla completa el  que la contiene ...

HTML

```
  <div class="row  border-bottom white-bg dashboard-header">
       <div class="col-md-8">
           <div class="flot-chart dashboard-chart" id="charting">
               <div class="flot-chart-content" id="flot-dashboard-chart"></div>
           </div>
      </div>
  </div>
<input type="button" id="fullScreen" name="fullScreem" value="FS" class="btn" onclick="PantallaCompleta()" />
```

Codigo JS

```
function PantallaCompleta()
    {
        var btn = document.getElementById("fullScreen");

        var element = document.getElementById("flot-dashboard-chart");
        if (btn.innerText = 'FS') {
            element.style.background = 'White';
            if (element.requestFullScreen) {
                element.requestFullScreen();
            } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                element.mozRequestFullScreen();
            } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
            }
            btn.innerText = 'ESC';
        }
        else
        {
            if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
                document.cancelFullScreen();
            } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                document.mozCancelFullScreen();
            } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
                document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
            }
            btn.innerText = 'FS';
        }
    };
```